# Selenium WebDriver: How to pass object locators with parameters in driver.findElement(<locator_value>)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm putting my `xpath` in a `JSON` file and have written method `getORData` in `jsonReader` class which is working fine. But when I'm running below code it is printing `By.xpath: //a[@id='accountLink']`.

My expected output is `//By.xpath("//a[@id= 'accountLink'")`.

Please let me know what is wrong with it. JSON Data is like: 
`{"xpath_signIn_button":"//a[@id='accountLink']"}`

```
public class ORConfig {
public static By xpath_signIn_button;   
public static void getLocator() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonReader.getORData();     
    xpath_signIn_button = By.xpath((String) 
    jsonObject.get("xpath_signIn_button"));
    System.out.println(xpath_signIn_button);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    ORConfig.getLocator();      
}
```

Comment: You can just add the missing parts. System.out.println("//By.xpath(" + xpath_signIn_button + ")");

Comment: Don't do this. Read up on page object model and follow it instead. Put your locators in your page object code. Your code will be faster, you can use all of the different locator methods (most of which are better/faster than XPath), and you won't have to deal with issues like this.